# What is the benefit of using inheritance in Mongo?

Tags: inheritance, mongodb

My app has a Post model and users can comment on a post. I'm deciding between using separate collections for Post and Comment or embedding comments within posts. Is there any advantage to using embed? I'm trying to find a reason why it might be better for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really inheritance, keeping Comments and Posts in different collections in good only if there is some situation in which you process them separately and one is called far more than the other.

For instance, if I had a site where a summary of the posts are displayed on the homepage and the comments are only displayed when accessing a specific post. I would keep them is separate collections (I would probably not even use MongoDB for the posts since simple caching would suffice) this way I can tune my Posts collection to be small and fast and my Comments collection to be slower and larger. I'm assuming that the traffic is such that homepage views are OOM more than specific Post views (this is not always correct).

There is also a case for keeping them together, for one it simplifies my data model by having only one object. For another I only require one query to fetch all the data for a specific page as opposed to 2 queries with 2 collections. And finally I maintain data locality which means sharding and Map/Reduce can be done more efficiently should the need arise.